# Сложная 3D фигура OpenGL

Tags: opengl, c++, 3d

У меня 3 вопроса:

1. Как сделать так, чтобы при вращении фигуры не вращались координатные оси? `glLoadIdentity()` не помогло.
2. Как реализовать возможность увеличения/уменьшения числа разбиений для аппроксимации сферических поверхностей? например задать переменную `int zoom` и динамически изменять её в зависимости от количества нажатия клавиши. Как написать такой цикл или условие?
3. Как реализовать возможность отсечения сложной фигуры по горизонтали/вертикали? вот этого вообще не понимаю..

Код одного примитива моей фигуры:

```
//основание - конус
    glPushMatrix();
        glTranslated(0, -1, 0);//перенос
        glRotated(270, 1, 0, 0); //поворачиваем

        if(view == 0)
            gluQuadricDrawStyle(quadObj, GLU_LINE);

        if(view == 1)
            gluQuadricDrawStyle(quadObj, GLU_FILL);

        gluCylinder(quadObj, 1, 0.5, 0.7, 20, 20);     
    glPopMatrix();

    gluDeleteQuadric(quadObj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)

```
glpushmatrix; 
glrotatef(x,y,z); 
ваша сцена\фигура
glpopmatrix;
```

остальное утром, если осилю смысл.

Comment: спасибо, попробую

Comment: void CALLBACK display(void)
{
 glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
 glClearColor( 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 0 );
 
 // сохраняем старое положение сцены
 glPushMatrix();
  //вращаемся вокруг осей Х и Y
  glRotated(alpha, 0, 1, 0);
  glRotated(beta, -1, 0, 0);
  Figura();
  Axes();
  //возвращаем координату на место
 glPopMatrix();
 
 auxSwapBuffers();
}

вот код, все равно вращается вместе с фигурой

Comment: glPushMatrix();
    glRotated(alpha, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotated(beta, -1, 0, 0);
    //сдесь вращаеться
glPopMatrix();
    //сдесь нет

Answer (score 1):

*На первый вопрос вам уже ответили, попробуем разобраться с остальными.*

### **2**

---

Способ, используемый в коммерческих решениях - сделать поддержку [**Level of detail**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_detail) в вашем проекте. В случае сферы необходимые уровни детализации можно даже не рассчитывать заранее, а вычислять и прогружать на лету *(поскольку конкретно для сферы это сделать просто).*

В случае некоторой неизвестной модели существуют также техники `LOD` на лету, однако в общем случае качественные алгоритмы `polygon reduction` выполняются долго и не являются реалтаймовыми. *Т.е нужно делать предобработку и хранить соответствующие уровни `LOD` вместе с вашей моделью; с этой задачей, кстати говоря, очень легко справляется любой современный 3d редактор.*

Если интересно, то есть неплохой [**референс**](http://lodbook.com/) по теме алгоритмов и применения `Level of detail`.

### 3

---

В общем случае тоже не реалтаймовая задача, поскольку необходимо выгружать все вершинные и индексные буферы для модели, выполнять перерасчет и отсечение треугольников и после этого загружать все обратно на `GPU`. Пара десятков таких операций на фрейм съест всю вашу производительность.

Поэтому, в случае, если необходимо нарисовать какой-то фрагмент объекта, например, до плоскости, то **рисуют весь объект**, а поверх него рисуется плоскость, перекрывающая ненужную часть. В этом случае графический процессор *(в большинстве случаев)* поймет, что бессмысленно проводить растеризацию перекрытых треугольников благодаря [**occlusion culling,**](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch29.html) и сильной потери производительности не произойдет.

Comment: что-то слишком сложно для простой лабы по графике, у меня обычный объект из примитивов

Answer (score 1):

Для первого вопроса:

```
glPushMatrix();
    glRotated(alpha, 0, 1, 0);
    glRotated(beta, -1, 0, 0);
    Figura(); 
glPopMatrix();
Axes();
```

Т.е. необходимо сохранять текущую матрицу в стек перед манипуляциями с фигурой и восстанавливать после. А если совершаются матричные операции над осями, то и для них тоже самое.